# How to convert a list of tuples into different csv files

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
List=[ ('1',['45','55','56','57']) , ('2',['200','202','202']) , ('3',['500','501','502'])]
```

As can be seen, three tuples of size 2.

I want to convert this list into three different csv files.

The output should be three different csv file with the names of "1.csv","2.csv","3.csv"

Comment: Should the lists be written on one line, or one value on each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the files you want are valid CSV files, they're so trivial there's no need to use the `csv` module to create them (or read them).

```
data = [
    ('1', ['45', '55', '56', '57']),
    ('2', ['200', '202', '202']),
    ('3', ['500', '501', '502']),
    ]

for dataset_name, dataset in data:
    with open('{}.csv'.format(dataset_name), 'w') as outfile:
        for item in dataset:
            outfile.write('{}\n'.format(item))
```

This assumes each item in the lists should be on their own line.

Comment: `outfile.writelines(dataset)` does not comma separate the data. It will be 45555657

Comment: @Paul, doh. And I assume you meant newlines, not commas.

Comment: Either way, it is run together as is.

Comment: @Paul, indeed; fixed now.

Comment: To get them all on one line you can use `",".join(dataset)`

Comment: @Paul, I know, but I'm assuming OP wants them on separate lines until clarified otherwise.

Comment: @Cyphase. Thank you. IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '1.csv'

Comment: @mar, looks like you don't have permission to write in your current working directory, a.k.a. the directory your terminal is in when you run the script.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the data in one row:

```
List=[ ('1',['45','55','56','57']) , ('2',['200','202','202']) , ('3',['500','501','502'])]

for filename, data in List:
    with open('{}.csv'.format(filename), 'w') as f_output:
        f_output.write(','.join(data))
```

This would give you:

1.csv

```
45,55,56,57
```

2.csv

```
200,202,202
```

3.csv

```
500,501,502
```